# Can we use KJV Bible version in mobile application

Tags: bible

We are using KJV version of Bible in our app distributed globally and we are based out of Canada. KJV is in public domain except UK. Does it mean that we should restrict the users in UK.

Comment: Why not use another public domain translation that isn't restricted in the UK? The KJV is also very old and shouldn't be used by non-experts.

Comment: Very good suggestion there. Thank you. We researched a bit and found KJV is used more widely but it is not suiting our needs to spread the word as much as possible. We found American Standard Version (ASV 1901) is in public domain which is readable. Do you recommend any other public domain translation.

Comment: @curiousdannii _The KJV ... shouldn't be used by non-experts_  I have been reading the KJV since I was old enough to read (65 years ago) and nobody told me there was an 'expert' certificate required. How do I get one ?

Comment: @NigelJ If you've been reading the KJV for 65 years you probably are an expert. But the KJV is 400 year old language and some words have changed their meaning, leading the casual reader to misunderstand. Something I'm sure you know.

Comment: is this really a Christianity question? seems more like a legal question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it pertains to legal issues and is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @NigelJ The big difficulty with the KJV is that while you may learn the disused words as you gain familiarity, when a word has changed meaning but the new meaning makes perfect sense in context you won't have anything to prompt you to check if meaning has changed. Two examples are [Phil 3:20](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/29943/6071) and [1 Thess 5:22](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/68711/6071). To responsibly read the KJV you need to be constantly checking that the words you know still meant the same thing.

Comment: @curiousdannii The real issue concerns the underlying Greek text. The very few archaic words is an extremely trivial matter in comparison.

Comment: @Sunny, The World English Bible was translated using the ASV as a base, modifying it to agree with the Majority Text / Byzantine manuscripts. It has no copyright, but demands an accurate text if you wish to use the WEB / World English Bible trade mark. You can download it in many formats from https://worldenglish.bible/ .

Comment: @Sunny, I am debating whether to write an answer, including the contact info for CUP: Permissions Department, Cambridge University Press, University Printing House, Shaftesbury Road, Cambridge CB2 8BS, UK. I think most web sites and apps do not bother to ask for permission. The (archived) page linked to from Wikipedia could be interpreted to give automatic permission, but that page is no longer on the site.

Comment: ...   In any case, I hope you can provide the traditional (KJV) text, and a modernized (WEB) text. At some point, you may want to add others, and you may be able to get free permissions from *some* -- definitely not most -- modern text publishers, if they like the quality of your app.

Comment: @BitChaser, Thank you for your thoughts. As suggested in this thread, I reached out to CUP and awaiting for their response. Also, as you suggested, I am providing other public domain versions such as Bible in Basic English, American Standard Version. Reached out to NIV but not sure if I get the permission.

Comment: @Sunny I don't think you'll get NIV, NLT, or NKJV permission unless you are willing to pay a lot. There are a lot of 'updated' KJV with free license, but largely unknown to the public. Ping me in chat if you want to discuss some more.

Comment: @BitChaser I would like to know more. I pinged you, I guess you are offline now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The protection that the Authorized Version, and also the Book of Common Prayer, enjoy is the last remnant of the time when the Crown held a monopoly over all printing and publishing in the United Kingdom.[166] Almost all provisions granting copyright in perpetuity were abolished by the Copyright, Designs and Patents Act 1988, but because the Authorized Version is protected by royal prerogative rather than copyright, it will remain protected, as specified in CDPA s171(1)(b).[j]

> Cambridge University Press permits the reproduction of at most 500 verses for "liturgical and non-commercial educational use" if their prescribed acknowledgement is included, the quoted verses do not exceed 25% of the publication quoting them and do not include a complete Bible book.[167] For use beyond this, the Press is willing to consider permission requested on a case-by-case basis and in 2011 a spokesman said the Press generally does not charge a fee but tries to ensure that a reputable source text is used.

[Wikipedia - King James Version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version)

Comment: Thank you. We are a startup working on the mobile application to allow users to read bible. So, in our case, do we need to check with Press for license?

Comment: In my opinion, legally, yes you do, but you need professional legal advice, not my advice.

Comment: If CUP "generally does not charge a fee but tries to ensure that a reputable source text is used" then the easiest way is probably to talk to CUP. If they give permission without a fee then you are fine and have saved a lawyer fee.